# Error overloads have similar conversions while building "OpenSubdiv"

Tags: c++, 3d, type-conversion, overloading

I encounter the following errer while building [OpenSubdiv] (http://graphics.pixar.com/opensubdiv/docs/cmake_build.html):

```
error C2666: 'OpenSubdiv::v3_0_0_beta::Vtr::internal::StackBuffer<TYPE,SIZE>::operator []' : 4 overloads have similar conversions
```

The code line that triggers error is:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < pVertEdges.size(); ++i) {
            cVertEdgeBuffer[i] = _refinement.getEdgeChildEdges(pVertEdges[i])[pVertInEdge[i]];
        }
```

the instance is:

```
internal::StackBuffer<Index,16> cVertEdgeBuffer(_childLevel._maxValence);
```

It seems to have some ambiguity in the overload operator [] in the class StackBuffer

```
template <typename TYPE, unsigned int SIZE>
class StackBuffer
{
StackBuffer();
StackBuffer(size_type size);
~StackBuffer();

public:
TYPE &       operator[](size_type index)        { return _data[index]; }
TYPE const & operator[](size_type index) const  { return _data[index]; }

operator TYPE const * () const { return _data; }
operator TYPE *       ()       { return _data; }
};
```

I change the compile from VS2012 to VS2010, but the error still come out.

Is this error due to OpenSubdiv's source or due to my Cmake configuration? I add all the dependencies as OpenSubdiv requires.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in OpenSubdiv (dev-branch)
https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv/issues/622#issuecomment-111051840